# connection string is not working in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

i registered my website on somee.com. for that i have uploaded MS SQL database. i was wrting this connection string in my code:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/nrcsaEntities.csdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.ssdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=My-PC;initial catalog=nrcsa;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

now as i registered somee.com is providing me new connection string that is:

```
workstation id=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=DuaZoya_SQLLogin_1;pwd=abcd;data source=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=nrcsadb
```

i have changed connectiong string in file web.config by replacing this first connection string with provided connection string by somee.com

**PROBLEM:**

This replacement is generating warning that:

```
 System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'user id'.
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you're using EF, you need to only replace the inner `provider connection string`.

Comment: @SLaks can you please explain me with example:)

Answer (score 4):

In the web.config file ....

```
     <connectionStrings><add name="nameofConnection" connectionString="Data   Source=servername; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; User ID=UserName; Password=Password;"/>  </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />  </system.web>
```

you can edit target Framework according to you.

from : http://dotnet-developers-cafe.blogspot.in/2013/08/create-connection-string-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 2):

You're using Entity Framework.

Entity Framework has its own connection string which contains a reference to the EF metadata (`metadata=...`) as well as the inner connection string to connect to the actual database.

You need to insert your actual database connection string inside the EF connection seting, in the `provider connection string=...` section.
You will also need to add `multipleactiveresultsets=True` to their connection string; EF needs that setting.

Comment: now it is saying  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. how to solvw this ?

Comment: @TameenMalik: Your inner connection string is wrong.  You may need to add `integrated security=false`

Comment: Thank's @SLaks .... now problem is [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]

Comment: i am writing this :  ` <connectionStrings>
  <add name="nrcsaEntities"
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/nrcsaEntities.csdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.ssdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;initial catalog=nrcsadb;integrated security=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>`

Comment: @TameenMalik: That isn't the connection string they gave you.

Comment: yes this is not what they gave me . this is what i have edited. What this should be? :(

Comment: You need to insert their connection string in `provider connection string`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44284/discussion-between-tameen-malik-and-slaks)

Answer (score 2):

Don't replace the whole connection string. You will need to remove the Integrated Security = true section and replace it with user=DuaZoya_SQLLogin_1;password=abcd.

Also change the data source to nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com.

You pretty much just need to replace values in your existing connection string with the values provided.

Comment: now it is saying System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. how to solvw this ?

Comment: Did you specify the user and password explicitly and remove Integrated Security = true? Check the Connection Strings snap in in IIS and see what the user name and password are.

Comment: Make sure you specify the user and password they supply, and remove Integrated Security = true. You can just change the true to false if you want, so Integrated Security = false.

Comment: No. Set integrated security = false. And make sure your password is what they gave you.

Comment: Change user id to user. Change pwd to password. You have to use the original attributes that entity framework understands.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44285/discussion-between-tameen-malik-and-field-b)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using entity famework, then your connection string will look like

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="BlogContext" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/BloggingModel.csdl|
          res://*/BloggingModel.ssdl| res://*/BloggingModel.msl;
          provider=System.Data.SqlClient 
          provider connection string=&quot;data source=[you somee.com connetion string];&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

what you need to do is simply change the value of data source from the actual connectionstring provided by somee.com

Comment: oh it says: `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'user id'.`

Comment: try this connectionString="metadata=res://*/nrcsaEntities.csdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.ssdl|res://*/nrcsaEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;data source=user id=DuaZoya_SQLLogin_1;password=abcd;server=nrcsadb.mssql.somee.com;database=nrcsadb;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"